# How to work with Timer, when app is in background

Tags: swift, google-maps, nstimer, dispatchertimer

Am calling one function for every 4 seconds using Timer

and if I tap on a button in the same viewController am navigating to google maps.

After navigating to google maps that function is not getting called

Here is by button action

```
@IBAction func navigateBtnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "comgooglemaps://")!) {
        let googleMapUrlString: String = "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(CDouble(pickupLat)),\(CDouble(pickupLong))&mode=driving"
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: googleMapUrlString)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

here is my code to use timer

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async(execute: {
        sendingLatLongTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 4, target: self, selector: #selector(self.webserviceCall), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        RunLoop.main.add(self.sendingLatLongTimer!, forMode: .commonModes)
    })
}
```

Comment: You cannot use a timer when app is in the background. It will be stopped. You can look at background modes which will give you a small amount of time once the app is put into the background. The only way is really using a push notification from your server.

Answer (score 1):

actually you can use Timer in background, but you must create BackgroundTask before see gist here: https://gist.github.com/phatmann/e96958529cc86ff584a9
Should be noted background task in IOS 11 maximum life time is 180 sec, after background task expires, your app falls to suspended mode, if you need perform some job in background periodically, use silent push from server.

```
private func startBarkgroundTaskTimer(time: TimeInterval) {
    backgroundTaskTimer?.invalidate()
    backgroundTaskTimer = nil
    backgroundTaskTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
        withTimeInterval: time,
        repeats: true,
        block: { [weak self] _ in
            guard let `self` = self, UIApplication.isBackground else { return }
            Logger.log("update location from BG")
    })
}
```